# What projection to use in POSTGIS for LAT/LONG and 'contains' queries

Tags: postgis, postgresql, coordinate-system

I would like to store latitude / longitude information in a POSTGIS database. I will need to query that data with simple contains query (for display on a map, so the bounding will be simple box) and lookup by lat/long.

As I'm new to all this GIS, what would be the recommend storage/column format? Anything that needs to be considered for indexes?

Comment: Please ask only **one** question per question.  Indexing is a ***huge*** topic all by itself.

Answer (score 7):

The column format for PostGIS is called [`geometry`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeometryType.html) and you'll probably need to read up on [all the functions](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.4/ch07.html) associated with managing spatial columns.

If you are getting the lat/longs from GPS or Google, the projection will be [EPSG:4326](http://epsg.io/4326).

**edit:** iant's comment brings up a good point about the `geography` type, and indeed if you are using EPSG:4326 it looks like [it will autocast to that type](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.5/ch04.html):

> The geography type only supports the simplest of simple features.
>   Standard geometry type data will autocast to geography if it is of
>   SRID 4326.

Comment: Geography might be a better choice here

Comment: Good point! Added to my answer.

Comment: Nitpick.  The type is geometry.   I nitpick because as I recall ESRI has a PostgreSQL type called ST_Geometry whic is a  different type from PostGIS geometry type.